# Eureka server not working with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I tried to update my microservices-based web application from Spring Boot 2.0.0.M3 to the newest 2.0.0.M4.

When running my Eureka server, I'm facing the following exception and the context won't load:

```
2017-09-19 10:22:05.455  INFO 16388 --- [           main] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d536e23]: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
2017-09-19 10:22:05.456  INFO 16388 --- [           main] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.HystrixAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d536e23]: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
2017-09-19 10:22:05.572  INFO 16388 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-09-19 10:22:05.573  INFO 16388 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-09-19 10:22:05.579  INFO 16388 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/lastn],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.lastn(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-09-19 10:22:05.580  INFO 16388 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaController.status(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
2017-09-19 10:22:05.582  WARN 16388 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
2017-09-19 10:22:05.587  WARN 16388 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'eurekaRegistration': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2017-09-19 10:22:05.589  INFO 16388 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-09-19 10:22:05.612  INFO 16388 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-09-19 10:22:05.615 ERROR 16388 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233)
    at fr.auchan.wheatley.discovery.DiscoveryApplication.main(DiscoveryApplication.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3526)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
    at java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(AnnotatedElement.java:258)
    at java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Class.java:3425)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:611)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.isHandler(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:217)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
```

I wondered if it was due to some configuration on my side, so I tried to recreate an Eureka Server from scratch with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 using the Spring Initializr.

The only fact of adding the *spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server* dependency to the POM triggers the error.

Here's the configuration:

- Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4
- Spring Cloud Finchley M2

Is there some incompatibility between Eureka and the last milestone version of Spring Boot? Or maybe some configuration point that I might miss? I didn't find anything about it in the migration guide.

EDIT: in the end, the same exception also appears on my client microservices when the *spring-cloud-starter-eureka* dependency is present  in the POM.

Comment: hi. I have the exact same problem. Reverted to M3, and the exception is no longer thrown

Comment: Hi,

Yes, I did the same as Spring Cloud Finchley doesn't seem stable with Spring Boot M.4.

However, I tried with the following configuration, and Eureka seemed to work:
- Spring Boot M.4
- Spring Cloud Finchley Snapshot.

I don't want to work with the snapshot version, but maybe this problem will be solved in Finchley M3 (hope so). Wait and see...